# Permission denied when nginx tries to read SSL certificate from inside docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose setup using Certbot and Nginx

```
version: "3"
services:
    web: 
        image: nginx:latest
        user: root
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html
            - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - certbot:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - certbot:/var/www/certbot
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443

    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot:latest
        command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot --email email@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d www.domain.com -d domain.com 
        volumes:
            - certbot:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./logs/certbot:/var/log/letsencrypt
            - certbot:/var/www/certbot

volumes:
     certbot:
```

Eveything works as expected, certbot creates the SSL certificates and puts them in the correct place for Nginx to read them.
The issue is Nginx does not have the correct permissions to read the files giving the following error on the logs.

```
2020/12/04 09:50:03 [error] 27#27: *1 cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib) while SSL handshaking, client: 31.187.58.166, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I am running the Nginx image as root as seen by `user: root` in the docker-compose yet Nginx still doesn't have permissions to read this file. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a false message. It 'can' load the certificate, but maybe it cannot validate it.
inx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate

Try this
sudo nginx -t
nginx will tell you what really happened